# Tabindex ignored when Enabled set to true in a validating event handler

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have three text boxes.

txtBox1 - Enabled=True - TabIndex=1

txtBox2 - **Enabled=False** - TabIndex=2

txtBox3 - Enabled=True - TabIndex=3

I have an event handler that sets Enabled=True for txtBox2 when txtBox1 is validating. My problem is that the cursor doesn't go to txtBox2 after leaving txtBox1, it jumps to txtBox3.

```
Private Sub Example(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtBox1.Validating

txtBox2.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Is there a way to have the TabIndex respected after a field is enabled in a validating event handler? I can use Select() but that breaks reverse tabbing through the fields (SHIFT+TAB).

Thank you!

Comment: maybe if you monitor for keydown, and on Tab key down you perform the validation and swap to the next textbox manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I posted the wrong solution so here is the correct one. Hans got me thinking and this is what I came up with that works for my needs:

```
Public Class Form1

' First you have to declare a variable
Dim m_TabForward As Boolean

' Capture the keystrokes to check for direction.
Private Sub GetTabDirection(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles _
                            txtBox1.PreviewKeyDown

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift) Then
        m_TabForward = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        m_TabForward = True
    End If

End Sub

' Enable the next textbox and select it. Because SelectNextControl
' takes a direction argument you don't have a problem with reversing order
' like you would using txtBox2.Select()
Private Sub ValidateFields(ByVal Sender As Object, _
                      ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
                      Handles txtBox1.Validating

    Dim ctl As Control = Sender

    If Sender Is txtBox1 Then
        txtBox2.Enabled = True
    End If

    SelectNextControl(ctl, m_TabForward, True, True, True)

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a simple chicken-and-egg problem.  The Validating event fires because the textbox lost the focus.  Which happened because you tabbed to the next control.  Which was of course txtBox3, enabling txtBox2 does not change that.

Easy to fix, the ActiveControl property tells you which control is active.  So write it like this:

```
  txtBox2.Enabled = True
  If Me.ActiveControl Is txtBox3 Then txtBox2.Focus()
```

Back-tabbing works properly as long as you have more than 3 controls that can receive the focus.

Comment: Thank you Hans I will give this a go immediately. Thank you!